# Prove that $\det A = \det A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am trying to use the formula
$$\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n, \sigma(n)}$$

Is this correct?
$$\det(A^t)= \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)a_{\sigma(1), 1} \cdots a_{\sigma(n),n}$$

If it is, why?

Also, then how can I proceed to prove that the two sums are equal?

Notes: $S_n$ is a symmetric group, and $\sigma$ is a permutation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$a_{\sigma(1), 1} \cdots a_{\sigma(n),n}=a_{1,\sigma^{-1}(1)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma^{-1}(n)}$$

Comment: @TheBosco For each $i$ let $j=\sigma(i)$. Then $$\sigma^{-1}(j)=\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(i))=i$$ Therefore $$a_{\sigma(i),i}=a_{j, \sigma^{-1}(j)} $$ and use the fact that $\sigma$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
\det A &=& \sum_\sigma \operatorname{sgn} \sigma A_{1,\sigma(1)} \cdots A_{n,\sigma(n)} \\
&=& \sum_\sigma \operatorname{sgn} \sigma A_{\sigma^{-1}(1),1} \cdots A_{\sigma^{-1}(n),n} \\
&=& \sum_\sigma \operatorname{sgn} \sigma^{-1} A_{\sigma^{-1}(1),1} \cdots A_{\sigma^{-1}(n),n} \\
&=& \sum_\sigma \operatorname{sgn} \sigma A_{\sigma(1),1} \cdots A_{\sigma(n),n} \\
&=& \det A^T
\end{eqnarray}

The first step follows because $\sigma$ is a permutation, so we can rearrange the $A_{1,\sigma(1)} \cdots A_{n,\sigma(n)}$ so the second index is in the order $1,...,n$.

The second step follows because $\operatorname{sgn} \sigma = \operatorname{sgn} \sigma^{-1}$ (which follows because $\sigma \circ \sigma^{-1}$ is the identity, and $\operatorname{sgn} (ab) = \operatorname{sgn}a \operatorname{sgn} b$.

The third step follows because $\{ \sigma | \sigma \text{ is a permutation}\} = \{ \sigma^{-1} |\text{ is a permutation}\}$.

Comment: I am a little bit lost, could you explain the steps you took please?

Comment: A simple looking proof with some deeper steps!